# How can Voldo safely get into his mantis stance with his katars towards the enemy?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

In previous games, there was a distinction between 2B+K and 3B+K. They would both go into the mantis stance, but the first variant would have katars away from the enemy, and the second would have katars towards the enemy. Now, it seems the only way to get into the mantis stance with the katars towards the enemy is to roll around on the ground like a lunatic or to start in blind stance.

Since the mantis stance is quite a bit more useful with katars towards the enemy, how can I reliably get into this position?

Comment: Rolling around on the ground like a lunatic is right up Voldo's alley, thought it may not be all that efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figuring out how to do this is effectively trying to figure out how to get into Mantis Crawl from various stances, specifically so that you're not in Blind Mantis Crawl.

#### From Standing, Facing Opponent

- You mentioned not liking not liking "rolling around on the ground like a lunatic," but you can use `2` or `8` from Death Roll and be in the stance you want immediately. A quick transition to Death Roll from this position is `2[A+K]` or `8[A+K]`, which is at least a vertical dodge. Not particularly ideal.
- My preferred move from this position is `[B+K]` - it's a mid hit, followed by a transition directly into the stance you're looking for.

#### From Standing, Facing Away

- From here, you can use the normal Mantis Crawl stance move `2[B+K]` directly.
- Another option in the same dodge vein as before is `4[A+K]`.

#### From Lying Face Down, Facing Away and Lying Face Up, Facing Opponent

- `2B+K` takes you directly into Mantis Crawl.

#### From Lying Face Up, Facing Away, Lying Face Down, Facing Toward, and Blind Death Roll

- Don't bother - figure out a good transition out of these stances and into the positions above, 'cause you're not going to get to non-blind Mantis Crawl from here.

Edit: After watching some of the recent WCG footage, it seems the more popular option for this is `1[K]` for a kick (with stun!) that turns you around, into `2B+K` (often following up with `K`, because `1[K], 2B+K, K` is a combo).

Comment: Another quick transition to death roll is 8A, which is also a jump. [B+K] is really, really unsafe, and definitely not the kind of move you just want to throw out there blind. I hadn't considered rolling out of death roll, so I'm going to give that a shot in my next few games.